# LaTeX: macro templates

Tags: macros, templates, preamble

Often at the end of astronomical papers there is written that it was created using the AAS LaTeX macro v5.2 . Do I understand this right that one can download such a template with all preamples at the beginning already set and that one only needs to write the text, insert graphics, tables etc. So you don't have to worry and mess around with the preamble?

Comment: Yes, many journals offer such functionality. In general, they will distribute a class file that you load as the document class. Then you can further specify any additional packages you would like to load (e.g. [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx)). The AASTeX class can be downloaded from here: https://aas.org/aastex/aastex-downloads, and is also available on CTAN

Comment: Some journals provide templates to get the output they want for their journal. If you want to submit a paper there, you should use it. It deals with fonts and margins mainly. Some provide own commands or require to use commands of predefined packages. So, if you are using a journal template, you have to take even more attention regarding the preamble.

Comment: If you don't want to submit to a journal, don't let a template limit you in expressing your ideas.

Comment: Did barbaras answer help you? You can accept it. If not, please specify the question by editing it.

Answer (score 5):

I can't speak for the AAS, but I am well acquainted with the templates from AMS
(the American Mathematical Society).  These templates are quite basic,
containing only a few packages that are known to be used almost universally,
along with recommendations in the form of comments regarding other packages
that are known to be compatible with the document classes.

**edit:** Templates from the AMS are *not* the document classes, but *outlines*
that consist, most basically, of three commands:

- `\documentclass{...}`
- `\begin{document}`
- `\end{document}`

A template may specify a few packages and recommend a few definitions (for example,
the AMS templates recommend the `graphicx` package and provide a "starter set" of
theorem definitions, as well as a number of comments with further recommendations),
but should not include anything that the author has to strip out before use; such
a file is what I would consider an *example*.

**end edit**

Different authors have different requirements, so loading in many packages that
*may* be useful is not good practice -- it may result in confusing conflicts.
With some experience, you will learn what packages and custom commands you
usually need.  Then you can create your own collection and copy it into
the preamble of a new file as a starter set.

When your work on the document is complete, review the contents of the preamble
and remove the packages and commands that you haven't used.  If you are
submitting an article to a publisher, the editors will appreciate it.

Comment: Can you add a remark, that one should *not* use a journal template if not submitting to a journal? Especially with respect to questions like [How to change a TeX template](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222518)

Comment: @Johannes_B -- this depends on what one's definition of "template" is.  in the question you cite, it appears that "template" = "document class"; not my definition -- i consider a template to be a framework or outline of commands (most basically, `\documentclass{...}`, `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) into which an author can insert the desired text along with necessary packages and definitions.  guess i'd better make that clear.  so that leaves your question re document classes; i have concerns there -- back to chat.