# How to change a TeX template

Tags: templates

How can you change the appearance of a TeX template? E.g. The AAS journal template. I don't like having the abstract on the front page and don't manage to force it on another page with `\newpage`.

Comment: Why do you want to change a journal template? Change the very basic *template* article available on your system.

Comment: The templates are provided by journal publishers (and copyrighted, most probably) Changing their template will lead to a rejection of a 'manuscript' ;-)

Comment: It's not nearly enough to say "I don't like having the abstract on the front page". You need to tell us: Where on the following page should it be? How wide, how much vertical offset to the subsequent material, which font (and which font weight), etc...

Comment: do you want it for writing stuff for your own amusement?  or is it for submitting a paper, or the like — in which case, just _don't_!

Comment: It's not for submitting a paper. I just like toe overall appearance of the AAS template, especially \documentclass[12pt, preprint]{aastex} - because the space between lines is smaller than in the manuscript. But I would like to have the abstract on an arbitrary page - either on the second or on the third if I write a dedication. After the abstract a ToC should be possible and then the text as usual. The fonts, offsets, width etc. should stay the same. I just like to customise the abstract position. Is there somewhere a description to study on how to specifically alter templates?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In general, you should be careful. However, this one is LPPL licensed, so you can change it if you rename it. The fact that it has a copyright notice is not the point. (Tons of stuff in TeX Live has a copyright notice. You need to assert your right to licence work in a particular way. Unless making it just public domain. Even then, you have to assert the rights in order to give them to the public!)

Comment: However, it is almost certainly better to start from a standard class - or another general-use class such as KOMA or memoir or whatever.

Comment: @cfr: I commented in a general on those templates by journal publishers, as they are commercial companies most often, being very harsh in maintaining their format. In this case I did not have checked the license by AAS, so you are right. Since the OP does not want to provide an article to AAS there is no problem at all (apart from the TeXnical one ;-))

Comment: @cfr Copyright exists whether you assert it or not, and in some jurisdictions you *cannot* place stuff in the public domain/renounce copyright (France, for example).

Comment: @JosephWright Yes. I should have been more exact. What I meant was: you can't license it or put it in the public domain or whatever without asserting the right to do so i.e. copyright. I didn't mean that you had to assert copyright separately. That is, saying 'I release this under the LPPL' or whatever is effectively an assertion of your right to do so.

Comment: A lot of helper activity was here, are there any news from your side? Especially, can you give us a minimal working example in order to explain your problem and make it understandable for us?

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,preprint]{aastex}
\begin{document}
\title{Thesis title}
\author{Hans Muster}
\affil{behind the Moon}
\altaffiltext{1}{\email{hans.muster@uni.somewhere}}
\newpage
\begin{abstract}
 ABCabc
\end{abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}`                                                 Just a minimal working example. I tried to force the abstract on the following page but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

> DISCLAIMER: The following solution is merely for academic
>   purposes. Is is *not* recommended to fiddle with journal classes.
>
> The Journal editors decide how papers in their journal should
>   look like. Any changes by submittors will be reverted in the
>   publishing process or the paper will be rejected at all. 
>   Changing the visual appearance of styles for preprints is very
>   strange in my point of view.

Now, what is going on? The `abstract` environment that simply
prints some text in the standard classes (and `memoir` and
`KOMA`-script) does something different, it saves the whole
abstract in a box. `\maketitle` later calls the abstract back; a
helper macro is called that does some stuff and calls back the
abstract box.

One needs to prevent `\maketitle` from calling the helper macro,
which will be different in other modes. Later one can reuse the
helper macro. The recurring use of `\makeatletter` and
`\makeatother` reveals that something is going on. Remember what
the combo of the two means: *Be careful, you are fiddling with
stuff you shouldn't fiddle with!*

Clemens suggested to define a new macro `\makeabstract` to use the box. Saves the catcode change in the document.

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprint
]{aastex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\tracingpatches
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@abstract@pptt}{\vspace{3em}}{\clearpage}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\@abstract}{}{}{}
\newcommand*\makeabstract{\@abstract@pptt}
\makeatother
\title{Thesis title}
\keywords{keywords title}
\author{Hans Muster}
\affil{behind the Moon}
\altaffiltext{1}{\email{hans.muster@uni.somewhere}}
\begin{abstract} \blindtext \end{abstract}

\begin{document}
~%\tableofcontents
\makeabstract
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `etoolbox` I would use `\csuse{@abstract@pptt}` :P

Comment: Iĺl have a look at this tomorrow. But thanks :-)

Comment: I mean in the document body, so no catcode change happens.

Comment: @Manuel or `\csname @abstract@pptt\endcsname` (or even `\csname@abstract@pptt\endcsname` since `@` isn't a letter). Works with and without `etoolbox` :)

Comment: @cgnieder I know, but *since* he loaded `etoolbox`, `\csuse` is defined :)

Comment: @Manuel I'd do something different, actually: after the patching define `\newcommand*\makeabstract{\@abstract@pptt}` and use that macro instead in the document body

Comment: @cgnieder Actually, good idea. I used that ;-)